# How to pass dynamic headers in urlopen module in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

In the code below I'm trying to get `UserId` from incoming headers and pass it to my backend using `urlopen` module but the header value is not been passed to backend.
In the header section below none of the commented statements are working.

Can you please let me know the correct format or any other way to invoke Post backend endpoint.

Thanks in Advance

---

```js
var UserId = apim.getvariable("request.headers.userId");
var targetUrl = apim.getvariable("targetUrl");
var urlopen = require("urlopen");
var options = {
  target: targetUrl,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    //'userId' : { $ : "request.headers.userId" }
    // 'userId' : { $ : UserId }
    userId: apim.getvariable("request.headers.userId"),
  },
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: apim.getvariable("inputReq"),
  timeout: 60,
  sslClientProfile: "api-sslcli-all",
};

urlopen.open(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) {
    // an error occurred during the request sending or response header parsing
    console.log(error);
    session.output.write("urlopen error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
  } else {
    // get the response status code
    var responseStatusCode = response.statusCode;
    var responseReasonPhrase = response.reasonPhrase;
    console.log("Response status code: " + responseStatusCode);
    console.log("Response reason phrase: " + responseReasonPhrase);

    response.readAsJSON(function (error, responseData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      } else {
        session.output.write(responseData);
        apim.setvariable("message.body", responseData);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with the code but you should verify that that you actually get a value for `apim.getvariable("request.headers.userId")`

Also remember that headers are case-sensitive in DataPower!